# How to send an email to a relevant person using user input in the bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I created a QnA bot. For that I added some questions and answers in QnA maker and am using it in my bot application.

If the user asks the question which is not existing in predefined questions, bot needs to get the unanswered question from the user. For that bot will ask the user's details like email id. Then bot needs to send email to the professional (bot already has the email id of him) and the content of the email should be unanswered question. Here I attached my code.

But I couldn't send the mail. After I enter the email id in emulator it says:

> Exception: Failure sending mail.[File of type 'text/plain'].

So how can I send the mail to particular person from bot.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace QNA_Bot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        private static string unans;
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            unans = activity.Text;
            // calculate something for us to return
            var text = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty);
            var url = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/b07f68a7-4a65-4330-8574-6529cf4c9391/generateAnswer";
            var httpContent = new StringContent("{'question':'"+text+"'}",Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "57feb2c9cd734fe48f624c4361dceb59");
            var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
            var httpResponseMessage = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic httpResponseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(httpResponseMessage);
            var replyMessage = (string)httpResponseJson.answers[0].answer;
           if(replyMessage== "No good match found in the KB")
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Sorry, I couldn't answer you...");
                await context.PostAsync("I can contact a relevant person and let you know...");
                await context.PostAsync("So could you give your mail id... If so type 'yes'");
               context.Wait(GettingMailIdAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }

        }

             private async Task GettingMailIdAsync(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            var ans = activity.Text;
            if (ans == "yes")
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Type your Mail ID");
                context.Wait(SendMailIdAsync);
            }
        }

        private async Task SendMailIdAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            var mailId = activity.Text;
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("From@gmail.com", "From Name");
            var ToAddress = new MailAddress("To@gmail.com", "To Name");
            const string fromPassword = "Pass";
            const string subject = "User_Question_From_ERPBOT";
            string body = "This Question was asked by" + mailId + " \n " + unans + "If you know the answer, Please contact the person through " + mailId+"The following is the question"+unans;
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, ToAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }

        }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you even attempted to do anything to resolve this yourself, or did you immediate decide to just come here and ask someone to do it for you?

Comment: *"Please anyone help me to solve this."* That's not a question, that's a use-case. Use-cases can't be *solved*, problems can. I don't see a problem.

Comment: Did you try to Google for `send email in C#`?

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce the issue with the code that you provided, I test your code to send email using my gmail account, which works for me.

> Failure sending mail.

To troubleshoot the issue, please try:

- make sure you provide correct credentials (`userName`&`password`)
- check if the port **587** is blocked
- check if you turn on "**Allow less secure apps**"

  [image]